# How to use front() on a const array

Tags: constants, d

I have this function, `extract()`, which takes a range and the name of a member, then attempts to create a wrapping range whose `front()` provides access only to the named member.

The problem lies in `Range.front()`, when R is of the form `const(T)[]`. The compiler indicates that the the function `r.front()` does not exist. I'm fairly certain there is something wrong with the interaction between the non-`const` R and the const `r.front()`, but I am not certain how to resolve it.

So, is my intuition correct? And in either case, what exactly is wrong, and how can I fix it?

```d
auto extract (string member, R)(R range) {
    import std.traits: hasMember;
    import std.range: ElementType, isInputRange;

    static assert(hasMember!(ElementType!R, member));
    static assert(isInputRange!R);

    struct Range {
        R r;
        bool empty ()() { return r.empty; }
        void popFront ()() { r.popFront; }
        ElementType!R front () { mixin("return r.front." ~ member ~ ";"); }
    }

    return Range(range);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. If you want to keep your implementation, you should to replace

```d
import std.range: ElementType, isInputRange;
```

on

```d
import std.range: ElementType, isInputRange, front;
```

and

```
ElementType!R front () { mixin("return r.front." ~ member ~ ";"); }
```

on

```d
auto front () { mixin("return r.front." ~ member ~ ";"); }
```

But.
Your implementation is too complexity

It may be more simplify.

Just

```d
auto extract1 (string member, R)(R range)
    if((hasMember!(ElementType!R, member)) && isInputRange!R)
{
    return range.map!("a." ~ member);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need `std.range.primitives.front()` if you are going to work with an array, and since names bind as closely as possible, there is no name conflict (If `R` implements `front()` it gets called instead of the one from `std.range`).

However, for reasons I don't understand, you can't selectively import it. You have to import all of `std.range.primitives`.

In any case, given a struct `S`:

```
struct S {
    string name;
}
```

And an array:

```
const(S)[] a = [S("A"), S("B")];
```

Calling `test.extract!"name"()` correctly returns `["A", "B"]`.